# Failed to start Cgroup management daemon

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

After upgrading my 18.04 to 20.04 it takes 5 minutes re-trying to load Cgroup management daemon with the following error:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Cgroup management daemon.
See 'systemctl status cgmanager.service' for details.
```

running `systemctl` gives the following output:

```
● cgmanager.service - Cgroup management daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cgmanager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-11-01 05:45:35 +03; 15min ago
   Main PID: 1277 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 01 05:45:35 bashar-ThinkPad-W520 systemd[1]: cgmanager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 01 05:45:35 bashar-ThinkPad-W520 systemd[1]: Stopped Cgroup management daemon.
Nov 01 05:45:35 bashar-ThinkPad-W520 systemd[1]: cgmanager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 01 05:45:35 bashar-ThinkPad-W520 systemd[1]: cgmanager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 01 05:45:35 bashar-ThinkPad-W520 systemd[1]: Failed to start Cgroup management daemon.
```

doing little research it seems Cgroups was removed even before 18.04 but during 18.04 no issues during boot.

is it safe to remove `cgmanager` as suggested by some questions/answers to fix the problem?